# Delimiting path using strtok()

Tags: c, path, strtok

I'm trying to obtain a file from its path.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char split_path(char *path){

    char *str1, *delim;
    char buf[255];
    int i, max;

    char *token = "/";

    for (i = 1, str1 = path; ; i++, str1 = NULL){
        delim = strtok(str1, token);
        if (delim == NULL){
            break;
        }
        buf[i] = *delim;
        max = i;
    }

    char last = buf[max];

    return last;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if (argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string delim\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char last = split_path(argv[1]);

    printf("%c\n", last);

    return 0;
}
```

So if I enter an input of /a/b/c/d , it returns 'd' which is what I want. 
But if I enter an input of /a/b/c/d.txt, it only returns 'd' without the '.txt', when what I need is 'd.txt'.
It seems to be only getting the first index after the last / . I can't seem to figure out the problem.
Help much appreciated.

Comment: If you only need the last part of the path, try `basename()`.  If you want to do it yourself, try `strrchr()` instead of `strtok()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is split_path is returning the first letter of the last good result of strtok.

Change split_path to return a string, and modify it slightly... something like this:

```
    char *split_path(char *path){

    char *str1, *delim;
    int i, max;
    char *last = NULL;

    char *token = "/";

    for (i = 1, str1 = path; ; i++, str1 = NULL){
        delim = strtok(str1, token);
        if (delim == NULL){
            break;
        }
        last = delim;
    }

    return last;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if (argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string delim\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *last = split_path(argv[1]);

    printf("%s\n", last);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how to do it two ways.  The easiest is to include `libgen.h` and use `basename()`, if this exists on your system.  It does what you wanted.  But if you want to write your own function, you can do it with `strrchr()`, which finds the last occurrence of a character in a string.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for strrchr()
#include <libgen.h> // for basename()

const char *my_basename(const char *path)
{
    const char *lastSlash = strrchr(path, '/');

    if (lastSlash)
        return lastSlash+1;
    return path;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return;

    printf("Full path     = %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("basename()    = %s\n", basename(argv[1]));
    printf("my_basename() = %s\n", my_basename(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Full path = /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.txt
Filename  = ddd.txt
Filename  = ddd.txt
```